# API to upload bulk offline conversions?

Tags: google-ads-api

I can able to upload single offline conversion to my adwords account through API.But I want to upload bulk conversions through API. Is there any way to upload bulk conversions in single API call. I am using v201402 adwords client library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the "MutateJobService" for this. This exactly serves your purpose
Here's the link:
https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201402/MutateJobService

Comment: Is it possible to upload the conversions without passing the client id of the account ? If possible means how can they differentiate accounts   which are mapped in MCC account.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. But, I have never tried it. Do you want to change some thing across all your client accounts?

Comment: No , I want to change/upload conversions in a particular account.

Comment: You should pass in the client id of that particular account in the field 'client_customer_id'. But you can always experiment and find if something works or not. :D

Comment: I tried the API without passing the client id and it's not uploaded also it's not throw any error. After searching the forums found this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/adwords-api/offlineconversionfeed/adwords-api/RIuAAWx5avA/Ql5A5rEUpCwJ .Thanks for you response :)

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/importing-conversions

Here is my c# code

```
public OfflineConversionFeedReturnValue UploadOfflineConversionsToExistingConversionType(List<OfflineConversionFeed> offlineConversions)
{
    try
    {
        // Get the OfflineConversionFeedService.
        OfflineConversionFeedService offlineConversionFeedService =
            (OfflineConversionFeedService)User.GetService(
                AdWordsService.v201509.OfflineConversionFeedService);

        List<OfflineConversionFeedOperation> offlineConversionOperations = new List<OfflineConversionFeedOperation>();

        foreach (OfflineConversionFeed conversion in offlineConversions)
        {
            OfflineConversionFeedOperation offlineConversionOperation =
            new OfflineConversionFeedOperation();

            offlineConversionOperation.@operator = Operator.ADD;
            offlineConversionOperation.operand = conversion;

            offlineConversionOperations.Add(offlineConversionOperation);
        }

        OfflineConversionFeedReturnValue offlineConversionRetval =
            offlineConversionFeedService.mutate(offlineConversionOperations.ToArray());

        return offlineConversionRetval;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new System.ApplicationException("Failed upload offline conversions.", e);
    }
}
```